# ConfigurationException: Trigger class 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger' doesn't exist

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am creating trigger using [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/triggers) but it is not working at all and I am getting ConfigurationException: Trigger class 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger' doesn't exist.

Steps I followed to create trigger:

1: I have compiled my java file using

javac -cp /CassandraTriggerExample/lib/cassandra-all-3.6.jar 
   AuditTrigger.Java

2:Jar creation :

jar -cvf trigger-example.jar AuditTrigger.class

3: I checked content of my jar file:

"unzip -l trigger-example.jar"

[image]

4: Copied this jar file into:
   **cassandra_home/conf/triggers**

5: Copied AuditTrigger.properties into:
   **cassandra_home/conf**

6: Restarted cassandra server

7: ./nodetool -h localhost reloadtriggers

8: In system.log i can see the entry:

```
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] 2018-07-22 22:15:25,827 
   CustomClassLoader.java:89 - Loading new jar 
   /Users/uname/cassandra/conf/triggers/trigger-example.jar
```

9: Now when i am creating my trigger using :

```
 CREATE TRIGGER test1 ON test.test
        USING 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger';
```

I am getting "ConfigurationException: Trigger class 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger' doesn't exist".

Comment: I am using [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

Comment: can somebody provide me some document or page where i can get deep dive info regarding Cassandra triggers latest use and implementation.

Comment: have you tried keeping the jar in cassandra lib directory with required permission?

Comment: @Laxmikant, jar is supposed to be placed in cassandra_home/conf/triggers right ? i did not find any doc or example which mentioned to keep jar in lib directory .

Comment: Right..but from error it look like it is not in the class path ..so just try and check

Comment: kept jar file in lib folder also, but still getting same error ?

Comment: @Laxmikant, any other suggestion ? keeping jar file in lib folder is not working.

Comment: i still think that it is an issue will class loading..please try 2 things 1. just check if the jar in lib has same permission as other jars 2. if they have same permission then instead of jar simply paster AuditTrigger.class in the lib folter with correct permssion (eg> 755) and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your jar isn't correctly packaged: if your class has name `org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger`, then it should be located under `org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.class` inside jar file...

See [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html) for more details explanation how classes are found...

Comment: @Alex, where can i get latest updates on cassandra triggers. I searched a lot but all the examples in net are very old and latest cassandra-all.jar does not have old api classes and methods.

Comment: There is example in the Cassandra repository: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/triggers - but usually the usage of Triggers is discouraged until you have really strong reason for its use.

Answer (score 0):

Did had a similar issue. Could be because you copied it but did not reload the trigger or created the trigger. Got it resolved by following the below checks and execution of command to re-load and create the trigger.

**Check**

Ensure that the class has name `org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger` and the same is located under `org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.class` inside jar file.

**CMD Command**

Go to the `bin` folder of Cassandra installed folder to run the `nodetool reloadtriggers` command as below.

```
C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\bin>nodetool reloadtriggers
```

**Execute the below statement at cqlsh prompt**

```
CREATE TRIGGER test1 ON test.test USING 'org.apache.cassandra.triggers.AuditTrigger';
```

Your trigger should be now available!
In case if still the problem persists you can try to restart the server once to see if the same is available.
Find in the below code what I used to publish a message to Kafka consumer upon every insert to Cassandra DB as an example. You can modify the same for update. I used `JDK 1.8.0_251`, `apache-cassandra-3.11.7`, `kafka_2.13-2.6.0` and `Zookeeper-3.6.1`.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.cass.kafka.insert.trigger;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.cassandra.config.ColumnDefinition;
import org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation;
import org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.Partition;
import org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Cell;
import org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Row;
import org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Unfiltered;
import org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIterator;
import org.apache.cassandra.triggers.ITrigger;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

/**
 * @author Dinesh.Lomte
 *
 */
public class InsertCassTriggerForKafkaPublish implements ITrigger {

    private String topic;
    private Producer<String, String> producer;
    private ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public InsertCassTriggerForKafkaPublish() {
        
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
        
        topic = "test";
        producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(getProps());
        threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 20, 30,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>());
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition partition) {
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(() -> handleUpdate(partition));
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param partition
     */
    private void handleUpdate(Partition partition) {
        
        if (!partition.partitionLevelDeletion().isLive()) {
            return;
        }
        UnfilteredRowIterator it = partition.unfilteredIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Unfiltered un = it.next();
            Row row = (Row) un;
            if (row.primaryKeyLivenessInfo().timestamp() != Long.MIN_VALUE) {
                Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cells().iterator();
                Iterator<ColumnDefinition> columns = row.columns().iterator();
                
                while (cells.hasNext() && columns.hasNext()) {
                    ColumnDefinition columnDef = columns.next();
                    Cell cell = cells.next();
                    if ("payload_json".equals(columnDef.name.toString())) {
                        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(
                                topic, columnDef.type.getString(cell.value())));                        
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private Properties getProps() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        return properties;
    }
}
```